# Conjuctive queries using Impala

Tags: sql, cloudera, impala

Consider two tables, `ratings` and `products` and the have some columns. I'm trying to query some data using

```
SELECT AVG(r.rating), COUNT(p.prod_id) FROM ratings as r, products as p;
```

which I saved as `script.impala` and the ran using `impala-shell -f script.impala`. I get the following:

`[user@localhost]$ impala-shell -f script.impala
*mumble*
Query: select AVG(r.rating),
       COUNT(p.prod_id)
FROM ratings as r,
     products as p
ERROR: NotImplementedException: Join between 'r' and 'p' requires at least one conjunctive equality predicate between the two tables
Could not execute command: select AVG(r.rating),
       COUNT(p.prod_id)
FROM ratings as r,
     products as p`

I have found no info on this kind of query in the [Impala docs](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-5-x/topics/impala_select.html#select). What is the correct syntax of this query? both work perfectly on separate statements.

Impala version is `Impala Shell v1.0 (d1bf0d1) built on Sun Apr 28 15:33:52 PDT 2013`. I know it's super old but I cannot change it.

Comment: you aren't specifying a join condition for the tables involved..which results in a cross join. I don't think *non-specification* of join condition is allowed in Impala. The error message is clear.

Comment: Could you give me an example of a join condition? I don't understand the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.  In your case, you have an query.  How about this?

```
select r.avg_rating), p.cnt_products
from (select avg(r.rating) as avg_rating from ratings r) cross join
     (select count(*) as cnt_products from products p);
```

Your query as phrased would return non-sensical results anyway.  For instance, it would return the product of the number of rows in the two tables.